# Execute some code when an object goes out of scope

Tags: c++, c++11

There are times where I want to be sure that some function call is executed before returning from an other function, or an integer is decremented.

For example consider this code:

```
void doSomething()
{
    try
    {
        .....
        .....
        return;
        .....
        .....
        .....
        return;
        ......
    } catch ( ... )
    }
    myvariable--;
}
```

I want to be sure that myvariable is always decremented, no mater if there is an exception, or a return call.
Is there any build in object in C++ for this, or I should create my own class that accepts an std::function and executes it when the object gets out of scope at the object destructor?

For example, in C# there is the try..catch...finally block where in finally you can put any code you want to execute before returning from the function.

Comment: Maybe use Boost.ScopeExit?

Comment: There's nothing in the standard, but it's not difficult to write your own "finally" class in the way you suggested.

Comment: Yes, exactly like Boost.ScopeExit, but I would prefer not to use any third party libraries.

Comment: What you want is RAII. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your own, class, that performs some action, in its destructor.

```
class DoAction
    {
public:
    DoAction (std::function<void ()> func) : m_func (func)
        {
        }
    ~DoAction ()
        {
        m_func ();
        }

private:
    std::function<void ()> m_func;
    };
```

And then, create an object of it, in a following way:

```
DoAction action([&] {/*Code that you want to be executed upon leaving the scope.*/});
```

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/nRvPgb).

Comment: Btw, `()` can be removed from the lambda.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Well, I have rarely used parameter-less lambdas, in the past, so I typed `()` out of habit. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

I often use `std::unique_ptr` for this, using lambda as custom deleter. It's slightly awkward, since you have to do `decltype()` for deleter type, but other than that, it saves you writing a 10-liner class.

Comment: I really like this approach because it's compact but if the unique_ptr holds a nullptr then the deleter won't be called.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct decrementer_raii
{
   T& var;
   decrementer_raii(T& v) : var(v) {}
   ~decrementer_raii() { --var; }
};

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    {
       decrementer_raii<int> dec(x);
    }
    std::cout << x;  // should print 0.
}
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/uNPGEn)

or more like your scenario:

```
#include <iostream>
template <typename T>
struct decrementer_raii
{
   T& var;
   decrementer_raii(T& v) : var(v) {}
   ~decrementer_raii() { --var; }
};

void foo(int& x)
{
   decrementer_raii<int> dec(x);
   std::cout << x << "\n"; // x is still the original value passed-in (14)
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i )
   {
      if ( i == 4 ) throw 10;  // force a throw 
   }
}

int main()
{
    int x = 14;
    try {
        foo(x);
    }
    catch(...) {}
    std::cout << x;  // should print 13.
}
```

[Live Example 2](http://ideone.com/LlWs8w)

Answer (score 1):

Your suggested solution of writing a simple wrapper class should work just fine. As far as I know there is no 'built-in' way of doing this in C++.

I wrote a simple class called `Finally` that does just what you wanted, calls a stored function as soon as it goes out of scope.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

class Finally
{
public:
    explicit Finally(std::function<void()> func);
    ~Finally();
private:
    std::function<void()> func;
};

Finally::Finally(std::function<void()> func)
    : func(func)
{}

Finally::~Finally()
{
    func();
}

void CallOnException()
{
    std::cout << "Function was called!" << std::endl;
}

void Run()
{
    const Finally finally(CallOnException);

    std::cout << "Throwing exception now!" << std::endl;
    throw std::runtime_error("Runtime error");

    std::cout << "This code will not be run." << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Run();
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        /* Handle exceptions */
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of this simple program is:

```
Throwing exception now!
Function was called!
```

Comment: There is a built in way, which you are using-- it's called destructors.

Comment: Thank you JonatanE

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a class that calls a function or uses a lambda etc in its destructor.

Here's one called [OnLeavingScope](https://crascit.com/2015/05/27/on-leaving-scope-part-1/).